# IP Addressing AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpc, elastic-ip

I had an instance running on EC2 until I stopped it temporarily. Upon restarting the Public IP changed. I read that this is allocated automatically, so is there a way to use another means i.e. Elastic IPS to get the same Public IP as before stopping the instance as the Applications that connect to these instances in the App store do so with the old Public IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Elastic IP address.

An Elastic IP address is a fixed [public IPv4 address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses) that you allocate to your AWS account. You can associate it with an EC2 instance, and it's yours until you choose to release it.

Note that an Elastic IP remains associated with your instance when you stop it, but only if the instance is in a [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html), not if it's in EC2-Classic (see the [differences](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#differences-ec2-classic-vpc)).

[image]

Comment: Can I give the Elastic IP address a certain address i.e. this particular address: 52.556.56.555?

Comment: No, you cannot dictate the EIP address. Amazon owns blocks of IPv4 address space and it will allocate randomly to you from the subset that it allocates to the Elastic IP pool.